# SystemArgumentException:The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to selenium Webdriver (using C#) learning to create POM framework.
Getting below error - code was working fine before

> Message: System.ArgumentException : The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null.

I have create Test Case which is calling another class and that is calling pageobject class.

Initial step of login works fine (same configuration)
and next time `PageFactory.InitElement` gives error.

```
public class TC_Sanity
{
    private static ExtentReports extent;
    private static ExtentTest test;
    private static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public IWebDriver driver1;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void report()
    {
        string CurDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy_hhmm");
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"U:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VisualLeaseFramework\VisualLeaseFramework\Report\MyReport" + CurDate + ".html");
        htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Dark;
        htmlReporter.Configuration().DocumentTitle = "TC_Sanity";
        htmlReporter.Configuration().ReportName = "KS-TC-Sanity";
        htmlReporter.Configuration().JS = "$('.brand-logo').text('').append('<img src=U:\\VL-Team\\VLImage.png>')";
        extent = new ExtentReports();

        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_Sanity()
    {
        test = extent.CreateTest("TC_Sanity");
        TestLogin login = new TestLogin(driver);
        login.loginTest();
        test.Info("Login Successful");

        SelectLeaseMenu leasemenu = new SelectLeaseMenu(driver1);
        leasemenu.leasemenuselect("New");
        test.Info("New Lease Creation Option Selected");

        login.logoutQuit();
        test.Info("Logout and Quit Successful");
    }
```

---

```
[TestFixture]
public class SelectLeaseMenu
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    public SelectLeaseMenu(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    [Test]
    public void leasemenuselect(string menu)
    {
        if (menu == "New")
        {
            LandingPage landingpage = new LandingPage(driver);
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            IWebElement projMenu = landingpage.LeaseMenu;
            action.MoveToElement(projMenu).Click().Build().Perform();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Moved to Lease Menu");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            IWebElement newLease = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("New"));
            newLease.Click();
        }
```

---

```
public class LandingPage
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    public LandingPage(IWebDriver browser)
    {
        this.driver = browser;
        PageFactory.InitElements(browser, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/input[2]")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement Searchbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that value of the parameter `browser` is null. I believe it is because a typo or you might forget to assign value to `driver1`.
See code below when you pass the variable `driver1` to `SelectLeaseMenu`, it should be `driver` instead.

```
[Test]
public void Test_Sanity()
{
    test = extent.CreateTest("TC_Sanity");
    TestLogin login = new TestLogin(driver);
    login.loginTest();
    test.Info("Login Successful");

    SelectLeaseMenu leasemenu = new SelectLeaseMenu(driver1);
    ...
```

So you can fix by:

```
SelectLeaseMenu leasemenu = new SelectLeaseMenu(driver);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have corrected the one you specified but the issue is after it navigate to lease menu page there is another page object class (Landing Page)  I am calling the error is coming when its trying to execute PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this); code.

Comment: @Kush Does the error occur at this step         `leasemenu.leasemenuselect("New");`?

Comment: No this error occurs at the step PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this); in LandingPage Class.

Comment: @Kush sorry, I mean the step in test case. Can you take a look at stack trace?

Comment: StackTrace: PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator, IPageObjectMemberDecorator decorator)   PageFactory.InitElements(SearchContext driver, Object page)   LandingPage.ctor(IWebDriver driver)  SelectLeaseMenu.leasemenuselect(String menu)  TC_Sanity.Test_Sanity()